# Canopy / Python acts as changes not saved

Tags: python, import, module

Below files are all saved in the same 'CurrenDir' location:

TestImport.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('whatever')
from testdef import *

what='Hey'    
test(what)
```

testdef.py

```
def test(what):
    print what + ' you!'
```

As expected running TestImport.py prints:

```
Hey you!
```

Now I change and save testdef.py to:

```
def test(what):
    print what + ' you???????'
```

As NOT expected running TestImport.py prints:

```
Hey you!
```

EDIT: However if I re-start Canopy changes are incorporated!

WHY?

Comment: That is am issue of canopy, not of python, It is working fine on IDLE and Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

I look forward for a more complete answer but here are the facts:

1) From: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

'For efficiency reasons, each module is only imported once per interpreter session. Therefore, if you change your modules, you must restart the interpreter – or, if it’s just one module you want to test interactively, use reload(), e.g. reload(modulename).'

2) The workaround:`reload(testdef)`